# How can I get a keyboard event when soft keyboard show's & hide in Phonegap/Android with Adjust Pan

Tags: android, cordova, keyboard

I am not able to get event for a keyboard when it comes & goes out in Android mobile. Also try with Adjust Nothing option but same result not able to get event.

A part of Code which I written in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
        android:name=".wlimbuat62"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.wlimbuat62.wlimbuat62.NOTIFICATION" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for `Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO` & `Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES`

Like sample given [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange), also see below sample code:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: above code is not working with `windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"` or `windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`

Comment: Do you you want to make it work with adjustNothing and adjustPan ? Can you please update your original question with more details?

Comment: Yes I want that soft keyboard event work with adjustNothing & adjustPan, already mentioned in Question.

Comment: Can you share the code what you have apart from manifest file? Looking at only manifest file we cannot understand where and what you missed, would be nice to some more code if you can share.

Comment: Actually code is ok and I am getting keyboard event with `adjustResize` , but not with adjustPan or adjustNothing.
Can you please try in any sample project if you have.